# Creating a perfect circle for all modes

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I think I am misunderstanding the concept of drawing a circle in android. Whatever I try I cannot get the circle to be perfect.

After many tries I managed to get it like this

Portrait Mode

[image]

Landscape Mode

[image]

And that looks terrible. My code is the following which creates my media player

```
<LinearLayout

           android:id="@+id/mediaPlayer"

             android:layout_width="match_parent"

             android:layout_height="wrap_content"

             android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"

             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"

             android:paddingBottom="10dp"

             android:paddingTop="10dp"

             android:orientation="horizontal"

             android:background="#ebeff0"

             android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation">


           <ImageView

               android:layout_width="match_parent"

               android:layout_height="18dp"

               android:layout_gravity="center"

               android:layout_weight="1"

               android:paddingLeft="28dp"

               android:src="@drawable/ic_repeat" />


           <ImageView

               android:layout_width="match_parent"

               android:layout_height="20dp"

               android:layout_gravity="center"

               android:layout_weight="1"

               android:paddingLeft="22dp"

               android:src="@drawable/ic_back" />


           <ImageView

               android:layout_width="match_parent"

               android:layout_height="50dp"

               android:layout_gravity="center"

               android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"

               android:layout_marginRight="11dp"

               android:layout_weight="1"

               android:id="@+id/playbutton1"

               android:background="@drawable/circle"

               android:padding="15dp"

               android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"

               android:src="@drawable/ic_pause" />


           <ImageView

               android:layout_width="match_parent"

               android:layout_height="20dp"

               android:layout_gravity="center"

               android:layout_weight="1"

               android:paddingRight="22dp"

               android:src="@drawable/ic_forward" />


           <ImageView

               android:layout_width="match_parent"

               android:layout_height="18dp"

               android:layout_gravity="center"

               android:layout_marginRight="28dp"

               android:layout_weight="1"

               android:src="@drawable/ic_shuffle" />



         </LinearLayout>
```

ID with playbutton1 is the image with circle. My code which draws the 'oval shape' is the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

   android:shape="oval">


 <stroke android:color="#d1d1d1"

     android:width="5dp" />


 <size

     android:width="50dp"

     android:height="50dp"/>


</shape>
```

Couple of questions

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Is there a way to just simply just make sure the the shape doesn't change regardless of screen orientation? (In XML)

**EDIT - SOLUTION:** The solution provided by deep worked, I replaced the image code with the following seems to give me the perfect circle in all modes.

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/playbutton1"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_pause"
                android:tint="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Loosk like the trick is `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

Comment: it is quite tricky as background does not maintain aspect ratio. Probably it is kind of a workaround, but I usually use another ImageView to show background in such cases.

Comment: use static same height and width for view ,It's will work fine :-)

Comment: please check my answer with screen shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mediaPlayer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="#ebeff0"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="28dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_repeat" />


        <ImageView

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="22dp"

            android:src="@drawable/ic_back" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/playbutton1"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_pause"
                android:tint="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </RelativeLayout>


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingRight="22dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_forward" />


        <ImageView

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_shuffle" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks @deep, i am suprrised how you tackle this issue, adding a `RelativeLayout` really worked, I now have a perfect circle in all modes :) Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#78d9ff"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Please find screen shot of landscape mode][image: Please find screen shot]**Try this way me this help you**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.test.myapplication.MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mediaPlayer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:background="#ebeff0"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgSuffle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/playbutton1"
        android:paddingLeft="22dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/playbutton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rtes"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"

        />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/playbutton1"
        android:paddingRight="22dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, what changes did you make and what is your `@drawable/rtes`

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <stroke
        android:width="5dp"
        android:color="#d1d1d1" />
    <size
        android:width="50dp"
        android:height="50dp" />
</shape>

Comment: Can you please check my new comment ?

Comment: actually, the the solution provided by Deep worked, i added a `RelativeLayout` and added an image inside that layout seems to be working perfectly - Thanks for your help though